# Save kernel on Acer Aspire One270 with Ubuntu 12.10 - Booting Issues

Tags: boot, kernel, aspire

I did search the forums for quite some time, yet did not find any answer to my problem...

I have an Acer Aspire One D270 with Windows 7 Starter and I've installed Ubuntu using the Wubi installer. When I boot to Windows 7, everything works fine, however, when I try to run Ubuntu, it gets stuck on a black screen at `stopping kernel messages` (or other lines), followed by some lines with `[   20.....]` and won't continue... Could anyone point me to a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1069031). The bug has been fixed, but in order to apply the fix to the bug you will have to successfully boot first. In order to do so, you need to blacklist the gma500_gfx module when you boot to install the updates.

In GRUB, add the kernel parameter `gma500_gfx.blacklist=yes` as a boot parameter, as per https://askubuntu.com/a/204261/12188 . Then install the updates, reboot and you should be fine.