# Fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10 won't boot on Asus X101CH Eee PC

Tags: 12.10, system-installation, intel-graphics, eeepc, cedarview

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10 in my Asus X101CH Eee PC, using a live usb which I made using startup disk creator, replacing Ubuntu 12.04. The installation ran smoothly, but when I boot, it goes to a purple screen for a second, then a lot of text like the following shows up in sequence:

```
Starting crash report submission daemon                        [OK]
Starting CPU interrupts balancing daemon                       [OK]
Stopping save kernel messages                                  [OK]
_
```

And the cursor just keeps blinking for hours. I can't log in. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> did not bring me to console mode.

I thought it might be a partition problem so I formatted the whole disk, by creating a new partition table using gparted in Ubuntu 12.04 live USB. I noticed that I can't try Ubuntu using 12.10 live USB either; it just went to a blank screen when I hit the 'try ubuntu' button.

But the same problem arose. I even changed the pen drive for the live USB a couple of times.

I happened to know that the Intel Atom N2600 Cedar Trail CPU in my computer is not well supported in Linux, I managed to install its drivers in Ubuntu 12.04, although the computer went blank during the installation.

Comment: Do not want the points since not registered but the solution posted here in the bug report: 
[http://askubuntu.com/questions/203269/xubuntu-lubuntu-ubuntu-12-10-cannot-load-xfc-lxde-unity-on-netbook-running-intel][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/203269/xubuntu-lubuntu-ubuntu-12-10-cannot-load-xfc-lxde-unity-on-netbook-running-intel

Comment: @helper234234 can anyone verify this? For a complete and total newcomer to linux (sorry) can someone babytalk me through the install? I bought this very netbook hoping to install and start learning Linux on the cheap, and I'm not even in the door yet!

Comment: similar experience with my asus netbook x101CH (atom N2600)
Lubuntu 12.10 worked fine until alpha3 !
See https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1058633 I gave up and installed opensuse 12.2 Linux 3.4.11-2.16-desktop.
It is less 'dummy'-friendly and perhaps slower, but it works.

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/203269/xubuntu-lubuntu-ubuntu-12-10-cannot-load-xfc-lxde-unity-on-netbook-running-intel **OR** http://askubuntu.com/questions/150025/acer-d270-graphic-support-with-gma3600

Answer (score 2):

1. On boot push F5 (or Tab, it depends on the tool you use to start it) and add to kernel option at the end: "text". In case you already have the "persistent" option you must remove it.
2. It will boot to a shell with user ubuntu
3. sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf (it will create this file):

> Section "Device"
>
> > Identifier             "Intel GMA3600"
> >     Driver                 "fbdev"
>
> EndSection

1. Save the file
2. Start the graphical session whith command:sudo service lightdm start

Source - http://linuxeeepc.blogspot.in/2012/08/lubuntu-on-eeepc-1025c-with-correct.html

Answer (score 1):

The same thing was happening to me and I just fixed it by adding the "nomodeset" parameter. Try this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132.

Comment: did't solve for me... it seems that it pick the wrong driver up during boot:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1069031

Comment: Did't solve for me either

Comment: adding on boot options `acpi_osi=\"Linux\"` it freezes on: `Starting configure virtual netwrok devices` I know that this does not solve it. Just interesting behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> **How to get started Intel Atom N2600 / N2800 netbooks after an upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10:**

1. After starting the machine press immediately the SHIFT button. This will start GRUB - boot options.
2. Select extended options. Some kernel versions will appear.
3. Choose a 3.0.2.x version - 3.05.x will cause trouble
4. The machine will boot.

**But:** Touchpad, WiFi and external media will not work. You need a USB mouse. To connect to the Internet/network, you will need an Ethernet cable.

At this stage it is possible to wait for an improved kernel. Important data can be sent via network or as an email attachment.

Good luck.